# Paypal Express Checkout - Disable Gift Certificates/Coupons

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm using Paypal API to perform payments on both physical and digital goods.

Everything is working as expected, but where i call set_express_checkout (using  AngelEye PHP class) and redirect the user to Paypal website, in the payment review under the section "payment methods" I see the option to redeem a Paypal's coupon.

I'd like to disable this option if possible, but in the documentation it seems there isn't any params related to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to disabling the option to use gift certificates/coupons on the PayPal pages during checkout, there is not a way to disable this feature in your API call.

Comment: thanks for support! I've seen payments flow that don't have this option (such as Vodafone Mobile website). Are they using another type of Paypal service (instead of express checkout)?